# replacing snprintf with c++ strings

Tags: c++, c, stdstring, printf

I have a requirement to replace C char buffers using `snprintf` with `std::string` and perform the same operation on them. I am forbidden from using `stringstream` or `boost` library.

Is there a way to do it?

```
const char *sz="my age is";
std::string s;
s=sz;
s+=100;
printf(" %s \n",s.c_str());
```

I get the output as

```
my age is d
```

where as required output is:

```
my age is 100
```

Comment: Actually, I understand boost case, but why stringstream is forbidden? They're both in std::

Comment: stringstream is not a library extension, it's in the same Standard Library as string itself.

Comment: I meant library extensions or header files.string stream is ina  different header file,isn't it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of job for which `stringstream`s were invented, so ruling them out seems fairly silly.

Nonetheless, yes, you can do it without them pretty easily:

```
std::string s{" my age is "};

s += std::to_string(100);

std::cout << s << " \n";
```

If you're stuck with an older compiler that doesn't support `to_string`, you can write your own pretty easily:

```
#include <string>

std::string to_string(unsigned in) { 
    char buffer[32];
    buffer[31] = '\0';
    int pos = 31;

    while (in) {
        buffer[--pos] = in % 10 + '0';
        in /= 10;
    }
    return std::string(buffer+pos);
}
```

Comment: @DominikC: C++11 is widely enough available that I treat it as synonymous with "C++" unless another version is specified.

Comment: @Jeffry: Thanks man for help.But as Dominik said, It turns out compiler at my place is opretty old and to_string is not supported.

Comment: @BasavNagar: See edit for a basic idea of how to write your own conversion.

Comment: @Jeffry: You are right.I guess I will have to write my own conversion now.

Comment: @jeffry: I come froma  c background mainly, but isn't this pretty weird that c++ before c++11 did not have a utility to do this kind of stuff??

Comment: @BasavNagar: It had `sprintf`, just like C did. Just didn't add anything to that. As for adding something new or different: I think in C++98 they'd already added as much as they thought they reasonably could (and given how long it took for compilers to implement even a large part of C++98, I think they were mostly right).

Comment: @BasavNagar: `stringstream`s ***are*** the "utility" to do this "kind of stuff"....  Isn't it "pretty weird" that your requirement forbids them?

Comment: @Tony D:  I sort of agree with you...But the requirements are given by my client and I donot have much of a say in it.

Comment: @BasavNagar: that's understandable and legit - just the "isn't this pretty weird that C++... did not have..." that I'm gently rebuking ;-P - I'm constantly surprised when people say "I have to solve this in C++ but I'm not allowed to do XYZ" then seem surprised there's no other perfectly elegant way to do it.  Most commonly, the same style of complaint comes from people trying to do error handling without exceptions.  Anyway - good luck with it!

Answer (score 3):

Edit your code as below,

```
const char *sz="my age is";
std::string s{sz};
s+=std::string{" 100"};
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

You need to concat a string to a string, not an integer to a string. 
If the age is varied in different runs, you can use `sprintf` to make a string from it and then, append to string `s`.

```
std::string s{" my age is "};
int age = 30;
char t[10] = {0};
sprintf(t, "%d", age);
s += std::string{t};
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Comment: yes,this would work and is one way to avoid to_string since it is not supported by my compiler

Comment: This doesn't help handle the situation where the number is in a variable with value unknown at compile time.

Comment: @TonyD: I edited the post to handle the case you said.

Comment: +1 from me then... cheers.  (In general, it may be easier to `snprintf(` the entire result into one generously sized buffer then construct the return string once from there).